# Wait for a jQueryanimation to complete within for loop

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I have something like the following code

```
for(i=0, j=10; i<j ; i++){
    $('#an-element-'+i).fadeIn();
}
```

How do I make it so that each iteration in the loop will only start once the fadeIn(); animation has completed?

edit---sorry my bad I had not included the 'i' in the loop

Comment: you can use [callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for` loops are synchronous, but animations are asynchronous.  You'll need to use recursion.

```
var i = 0, j = 10;
(function fadeNext () {
    if (i < j) {
        $('#an-element-' + i++).fadeIn(fadeNext);
    }
}) ();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq9mH/

Comment: Thanks, there were a few similar answers but this was the simplest.  As you say for loops are not suitable for this (without using delay)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your loop will just fade in the same element 10 times.

In any case, what you need is to put the call in the callback of the fadein method : http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Something like this should work (not tested)

```
var counter = 10;
function fadeIn(elem) {
   $(elem).fadeIn('slow', function(){
       if (counter > 0) {
          fadeIn(elem); //up to you how you figure out which element to fade in
       }
   });
   counter--;
}

//var elem = $('.something');
fadeIn(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code after an animation by placing it in a function passed as the callback parameter:

```
$("#foo").fadeIn("slow",function () {
  alert("done");
});
```

But it is not quite clear what you're trying to do. Are you fading the same element 10 times?

Comment: sorry for the confusion I have adjusted the code slightly.  The problem is that the for loop does not wait for the callback and just carries on.

Using this snippet all of the elements fade in at the same time and then I get 10 alert boxes all at once.

Comment: @matthew Sorry, this was not intended as a full solution for ten elements, just an example of the callback syntax. The recursive solution in the accepted answer is optimal AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0, j = 10; i < j; i++) {
    $('.try').each(function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

You can change the time duration inside the delay function. [Here is the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CV7fd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a fixed delay for all the item you may use this line of code:

```
 $(this).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

instead of

```
  $(this).fadeIn();
```