# for loop animate element - checking top position on loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-animate, position

I have the following javascript using jquery code:

```
function MakeAnimation(anim_times)
{
    for (k=1; k<=anim_times; k++)
    {
        if ( $("#one").position().top >= 250 ) {
            $("#one").animate({ top: '50px' }, 200, function() {});
        } else {
            $("#one").animate({ top: '+=50' }, 200, function() {});
        }
    }
}
```

and on the html body:

```
<button onclick="MakeAnimation(1);">step 1</button>
<button onclick="MakeAnimation(20);">step 20</button>
<div id="one" style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:50px;"></div>
```

both buttons calling the same function, but when the function called with 20 times for for loop... the 5th line [ if ( $("#one").position().top >= 250 ) { ] does not work

any suggestions ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working as expected. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/2dM9V/1/) for this.

Sorry, my bad! To answer AkisC's question, `for` loops are synchronous, but `animations` are asynchronous (ref. [Wait for a jQueryanimation to complete within for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252184/wait-for-a-jqueryanimation-to-complete-within-for-loop)).
Thus, for the 2nd button, we always get '50' as  the top value on every iteration and the `if ( $("#one").position().top >= 250 ) {` is never executed.

I've modified my fiddle with the new approach: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/3SSeu/

Comment: the animation works, but as AkisC states, the 5th line "if ( $("#one").position().top >= 250 )" is not taken into account during the loop

Comment: Yes! I did not know that the animations were asynchronous. Thanks for the answer and thanks for fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ucures/1/edit)*

All you need to do is to multiply the `n` times the `MakeAnimation` is called, **without a loop**, and...

all you need is to use the **step** function to retrieve the top position property value.
Don't be afraid, it's available by default inside the `animation` method:

```
function MakeAnimation(n){
  n=n+1;         // I used n=n+1 cause you already start from 50px top...
  $('#one').animate({ top: 50*n },{
       step: function(now) {     // the step function!
          if(now>=250){
              $(this).stop().animate({top: 50 }, 200);
          }
       },
       easing: 'linear',  // the default easing in animations is 'swing'
       duration: 200*n
    }); 
}
```

From the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step